# How to select elements with a specific array length

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

In an **each function**, I search through the DOM for many elements with a specific **className**. This ClassName, according to its length, will create an **array** that is long 2 or 4.
I need to select these two type of element separately in order to act differently.
How can I do that?

```
<div class="foo-1"></div>
<div class="foo-1"></div>
<div class="foo-1-boo-2"></div>
```

jQuery

```
$( '[class*=foo-]' ).each(function() {
  var foo = $( this );
  var fooArray = foo.attr( 'class' ).split( '-' );
  var arrayLength = fooArray.length;
});
```

the **console** will return that there are **3 elements**, two of them have length **2** and one **4**.
I need to separate these two results in order to act differently as they were variables.
I need something like:

```
var caseA = (foo with an arrayLength === 2);
var caseB = (foo with an awwayLength === 4);
```

Comment: If you are willing to use underscore you can do `_.where(collection, {length: n})`

Comment: And you can't target by the actual class values? Seems like that would be less fragile. What if some plugin/library/widgety thing/developer adds classes? Your app breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you want these as jQuery sets instead of arrays so you can easily manipulate them en masse with jQuery. So this will do it:

```
var caseA = $('[class*=foo-]').filter(function() {
   return $(this).attr("class").split("-").length === 2;
});

var caseB = $('[class*=foo-]').filter(function() {
   return $(this).attr("class").split("-").length === 4;
});
```

If you have tons of elements and it proves to be slow you can optimize this slightly by making it more complex and using one `each` instead of filter. But I wouldn't bother until it proves to be necessary.

Answer (score 2):

One possible way is to use [`.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method with a function as an argument:

```
var elements = $('[class*=foo-]'),
    caseA = elements.filter(function() {
        return this.className.split('-').length === 2;
    }),
    caseB = elements.filter(function() {
        return this.className.split('-').length === 4;
    });

console.log(caseA.length, caseB.length);
```

Comment: whats the difference between filter and map??

Comment: `.map()` creates a new array, `.filter()` reduces the set of matched elements @EhsanSajjad

Answer (score 0):

Another possible way is to just use a conditional statement -

```
$('[class*=foo-]').each(function () {
    var foo = $(this);
    var fooArray = foo.attr('class').split('-');
    var arrayLength = fooArray.length;
    (2 == arrayLength ? console.log('to do something') : '');
    (4 == arrayLength ? console.log('do something for') : '');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I mixed two solutions in the comment of this post:

```
var caseA = col.filter(function() {
  return this.className.split( '-' ).length === 2;
});
var caseB = col.filter(function() {
  return this.className.split( '-' ).length === 4;
});
```